# jquery - How to return default height toogle automaticly by clicking another place

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here, I have a working toogle code,so I have added some code that when click another place also return to default height(32px),but not working.

```
var toggled = false;
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.changeHeight').css('height', toggled ? '32px' : '65px');
  toggled = !toggled;
});

$(document).click( function(){  // if click another place will set default height
    $('.changeHeight').css('height','32');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element `.dropdown-toggle` is part of the `document`. Click on it will fire both event handlers. When it's clicked, you must prevent the documents event handler from being notified with `stopPropagation()`. Like this:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.changeHeight').css('height', toggled ? '32px' : '65px');
    toggled = !toggled;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing "px"?

```
$(document).click( function(){  // if click another place will set default height
    $('.changeHeight').css('height','32px');
});
```

You could also add a class on toggle, and remove it again. See more info on [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) in jQuery

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.changeHeight').toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

Comment: Yup,i have missed px on that,but it's working when add e.stopPropagation() on that as balzafin's code. :D